# lapply - create new variables with variations of .SDcols

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a large dataset with a few core variables of interest that I need to compute many different operations on.  I have a vector of these variables, `cols`, in a data table, `dt`, and I am trying to use `lapply` to create new variables.  I am having trouble when it comes to creating new variables that need to use multiple existing variables in the data table, which have names that are built around the core variables.  Here is an example (code runs through here):

```
dt = data.table( id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), x = 1:6, y = 7:12, z = 13:18) ## example data
cols = c("x","y","z") ## my list of variables
dt[ , paste0(cols, ".avg") := lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T)), by = .(id), .SDcols = cols]
```

I want to continue creating new variables this way, but I'm having a hard time referring to the new columns I have created through the previous `lapply` steps. I want to calculate the difference between column `x` and `x.avg`, but I keep running into errors.  I have tried variations of the following, all which result in errors:

```
dt[ , paste0(cols,".diff") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x-eval(paste0(x,".avg"))), .SDcols = cols]
Error in x-eval(paste0(x,".avg")) :
    non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I want an `lapply` step that is equivalent to the following:

```
dt[ ':=' (x.diff = x-x.avg, 
          y.diff = y-y.avg,
          z.diff = z-z.avg)]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Using `set()` instead of `.SDcols`...

```
cols <- c("x", "y", "z")
for (col in cols) {
  set(dt, j = paste0(col, ".diff"), value = dt[[col]] - dt[[paste0(col, ".avg")]])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with `[]`, you could use `Map` with `mget`

```
dt[, paste0(cols, '.diff') := Map(function(var, avg) var - avg,
                                 mget(cols), 
                                 mget(paste0(cols, '.avg')))]

dt
#    id x  y  z x.avg y.avg z.avg x.diff y.diff z.diff
# 1:  1 1  7 13   1.5   7.5  13.5   -0.5   -0.5   -0.5
# 2:  1 2  8 14   1.5   7.5  13.5    0.5    0.5    0.5
# 3:  2 3  9 15   3.5   9.5  15.5   -0.5   -0.5   -0.5
# 4:  2 4 10 16   3.5   9.5  15.5    0.5    0.5    0.5
# 5:  3 5 11 17   5.5  11.5  17.5   -0.5   -0.5   -0.5
# 6:  3 6 12 18   5.5  11.5  17.5    0.5    0.5    0.5
```

In this example your anonymous function is just subtraction, so you could write this more compactly as

```
dt[, paste0(cols, '.diff') := Map('-', mget(cols), mget(paste0(cols, '.avg')))]
```